# How can I put thumb conditional instruction into IT block

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I'm porting some inherited codes to my current platform. When I compiling it, it reports some error about arm assembler codes.

The message shows:

```
| {standard input}:7236: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `movne r0,r2'
| {standard input}:7237: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `biceq r0,r0,#0xff'
| {standard input}:7238: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `biceq r0,r0,#0xf00'
```

I'm a totally newbie to arm assembler, so my question is how to make below codes into `IT` block. Just as required by the compiler.

```
"movne   r0, r2;\n"
"biceq  r0, r0, #0xff;\n"
"biceq  r0, r0, #0xf00;"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "IT block" refers to up to 4 instructions made conditional by a single [`IT` ("If-Then") instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1361289872225.html). Whilst you have two different conditions there, they are logical opposites so can still be covered by a single `IT` thanks to the additional "Else" encoding. With one `ne` conditional followed by two `eq` conditionals, the appropriate instruction to proceed them with would be (I for *if*, then T for *then* as `movne`, E for *else* as `biceq` and another E for *else* as another `biceq`):

```
ITEE   ne
movne  r0, r2
biceq  r0, r0, #0xff
biceq  r0, r0, #0xf00
```